# write json data from kafka to s3 in parquet format

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am writing a streaming application (Flink,Kafka,S3) which puts data onto Kafka in JSON format and I need to write data to S3 in Parquet format.

I searched a lot of places and read questions on stackoverflow but I am not getting a clear answer that is it mandatory to read data in AVRO format in flink if I want to write parquet to s3?

I need to go from JSON -> AVRO -> Parquet?

Or JSON -> Parquet is possible using kafka, flink, S3

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to achieve that as long as the schema of the input is more or less static. 
The idea is to first conver JSON to avro, you can use for example this converter: https://github.com/allegro/json-avro-converter.

Then You can write the output to s3. To do that You can create a `StreamingFileSink` that uses the `ParquetAvroWriters` under the hood. Something like:

```
StreamingFileSink
  .forBulkFormat([somePath], ParquetAvroWriters.forGenericRecord(schema))
  .build()
```